# Trouble displaying data from firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to present some data from Firebase to a webpage, and I´m following this Firecast totorial: [Firebase tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=noB98K6A0TY&t=56s)

This is exactly what I need, but I can't get it to work. There is no data showing up.
Here is the code:

```js
(function() {

  // Initialize Firebase
  const config = {
    apiKey: "myKey",
    authDomain: "myApp.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://myApp.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "myId",
    storageBucket: "myApp.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxx"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  //Get elements
  const preObject = document.getElementById('object');

//Create refrence
const dbRefObject = firebase.database().ref().child('object');

//Sync object changes
dbRefObject.on('value', snap => console.log(snap.val()));


}());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html
<html>
    <head
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <title>Test</title>
         <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/live/3.1/firebase.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Test
        <!-- Value -->
        <pre id = "object"></pre>
        
        <!-- Child -->
       <script src ="App.js"></script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where you want your data?Please check console(crtl + shift + i) to see if you are getting data right, as you are logging it in console

Comment: What's the problem with the code? Are there any messages showing in the JavaScript console of your browser when you run it?

Comment: I was not aware of the console function (I´m very new to this) but that helped me out in finding out what was wrong. I had, as you correctly pointed out, only sent the data to the console.. Thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

to be able to read and write to your database you need to change database rules to be like this

[image]

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true ,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

of course that's, only in development..

here is jsfiddle so you can see results from my database

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/mkdizajn/cyg1x709/

Comment: Not safe. What to do in prod?

Comment: no, defaults are: `"auth != null",` for production use some of built-in auth providers, or user/pass (not so good)